# ssh config - send selected keys to agent

Tags: ssh, config, ssh-keys, ssh-config

I'm writing my `ssh config` file and want to send agents with selected keys. No keys are to leave my local machine and the sent agents may only have the necessary keys. All keys require passwords. I don't want to type password multiple times in sequence, e.g. when accessing `server`, but don't mind entering it again whenever I access a machine. The following shows how I want to connect to the different servers:

```
local [--> git (git key)]
local --> frontend (compute key)
local --> frontend (compute key) --> server (compute key)
local --> frontend (compute key) [--> git] (git key)
local --> otherserver (passwort & app)
local --> otherserver (passwort & app) [--> git] (git key)
local --> somwherelse (else key)
```

My local `ssh config`:

```
Host server
 HostName server.compute.net
 User user1
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentitiesOnly yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_compute
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_git
 ProxyJump frontend

Host frontend
 HostName frontend.compute.net
 User user1
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentitiesOnly yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_compute
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_git

Host otherserver
 Hostname otherserver.com
 User user2
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentitiesOnly yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_git

Host somwhereelse
 Hostname somewhereelse.com
 User user3
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentitiesOnly yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_else

Host git
 Hostname git.url.com
 IdentitiesOnly yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_git
```

But when I try `git pull` on `frontend`, I get:

```
git@git.url.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Locally, git access works. I made sure an agent was running before logging in to `frontend`. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you allowing agent forwarding, so that the `ssh` process on `frontend` has access to the agent running on `local`?

Comment: Possibly not. I connect with ```ssh frontend```. What do I have to do to allow agent forwarding?

Comment: You can either use the `-X` option when you run `ssh`, or use the `ForwardAgent` option in your config file to enable it automatically for specific hosts.

Comment: adding ```ForwardAgent``` to ```config``` worked, ```ssh -X``` didn't,  but ```ssh -A``` did. If you write a short answer, I'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that; `-X` is *X11* forwarding. My man-page skimming skills are fading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `ssh` on one of the remote hosts to use keys stored in the `ssh-agent` running on `local`, you must enable agent forwarding, either by using the `-A` option on the command line or by adding `ForwardAgent yes` to the configuration for the remote host.